Why isn’t there a ground on my switch that controls outlet?
I have a switch in a metal box. 1 brown wire 1 red wire. It controls a receptacle in a metal box. The wires at the receptacle are 1 white 1 brown. Why?
I want to change receptacle to a gfci and then add one receptacle after the gfci receptacle.
There is no actual ground wire. Do I need one???
Also it is a single pole toggle switch and I want to change that to a rocker switch. 15 amp

I tested the outlet when it was disconnected from metal box. Open ground. I connected back to metal box and now it’s saying Correct. So I’m grounded at that outlet right??

That is absolutely normal for a metal box, whether used with metal conduit as ground or ground wire (which connects to the metal box). Switches are always allowed to ground this way. Receptacles can if they are "self-grounding", which all the good ones are.

If the wires are in metal conduit(not cable), the conduit can act as ground.
Some switches and receptacles are self grounding though the mounting screws.
GFCI does not require a ground to work.  Quite often they are used to add safety to old ungrounded circuits.
If the circuit is grounded, the test is to use a multi-meter between the hot/live wire and the metal box.  It should read the local standard voltage.  If not grounded then the meter should read 0 volts.

Why the different colored wires?

I suspect your brown wires are actually faded black. But in conduit generally (my county has some strange restrictions...), white and gray are neutral, green, yellow/green and bare are ground (but metal conduit can be the ground by itself) and anything else: black, red, yellow, blue, pink, orange - is hot, switched hot, etc. and the color only has meaning in the electrician's mind but not in code.

@Jamie  In conduit, white can only be used as neutral.  Older switches do not have neutral required in the box, so in conduit they must use hot/live colours.  One for always hot and one for the switched hot.

So when I change the toggle switch to the paddle switch (which only has 2 golds screws) does it matter what wires go to what screws?

@Jamie  It does not matter.  The switch works either way.

Thanks for the help
